# "This editor is deprecated and we'll remove it after 1.59 of VS Code"- on vs code Jupiter extension

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have the Jupiter extension on my vs code with the following message:
"This editor is deprecated and we'll remove it after 1.59 of VS Code."

when will it be removed, and, more importantly:
is there **anyway** i can keep using the current version?

thanks

Comment: That error message (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/search?q=%22This+editor+is+deprecated%22&type=code) also contains a link to the team blog with all details, https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/08/05/notebooks

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the ipynb file
2. Go to the VSCode Explorer window on the left
3. Right click on the ipynb file
4. Select "Open in Notebook Editor"